# What is wrong with following javascript code

Tags: javascript

what is wrong with the following code? I had problem to mix double quotes, with single quotes. so, I defined separate method for onclick. Some how it seems syntax is not right

```
<table style='border-style:none; cursor:pointer;' onclick="myFunc()" >


function myFunc() {
    width1= getWindowDim().width; 
    height1= getWindowDim().height; opt23='resizable=yes,fullscreen=yes,location=no,toolbar=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,fullscreen=yes,width='+width1 +',height='+heigh1;
    window.open('http://ibm.com','popupwin',opt23); 
}
```

Comment: You're missing quotes around your javascript. To make it easier, define your function elsewhere and simply point using the function name. This will also improve readability a _lot_.

Comment: You have no quotes around your HTML attribute. This is a perfect demonstration why one shouldn't use inline event attributes.

Comment: if an attrib value needs to use attrib invalid chars (like >), a space, an equal, a quote or an apos, then you need to quote the attrib value. in your case, you use spaces, =, and apos, so you need quotes (") around the attrib value

Comment: code is not readable

Comment: I don't get why all the downvotes? the OP is clearly asking for help and has explained what their struggle was..

Comment: @CᴴᵁᴮᴮʸNᴵᴺᴶᴬ: people are taking revenge for the OP using the trifecta of inline styles, inline events, and window.open(), for the win. i like the implicit globals and do-nothing function wrap too.

Comment: @dandavis then surely the appropriate action would be to answer the question explaining the errors of their way? I agree with downvoting if the question is not good or shows no thought, but there has clearly been a thought process here.

Comment: "thought process" in regard to voting? shaw. people are motivated by emotions. people are also lazy and clicking is easier than typing. still i agree it's not helpful and that's why i don't downvote. when i get downvoted, i've noticed it's usually because i ruffled feathers more than posting a bad answer...

Comment: @CᴴᵁᴮᴮʸNᴵᴺᴶᴬ - it has nothing to do with code styles, the op hasn't described what problem they are having and it is just asking users to guess what the problem is (for the record I haven't downvoted this time)

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery for height and width it may work

```
     $(window).height();   // returns height of browser viewport
 $(document).height(); // returns height of HTML document
 $(window).width();   // returns width of browser viewport
 $(document).width(); // returns width of HTML document
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, onclick had missing double quote

```
<table style="border-style:none; cursor:pointer;" onclick="myFunc()" >

function myFunc() {
    width1 = getWindowDim().width; 
    height1 = getWindowDim().height;
    opt23 = 'resizable=yes,fullscreen=yes,location=no,toolbar=no,' + 
            'directories=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,' + 
            'fullscreen=yes,width= ' + width1 + ',height=' + heigh1;
    window.open('http://ibm.com','popupwin',opt23); 
}
```